# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conflict

I have checked a lot of forums, but i did't find a solution. 
site -> http://dszerszen.pl/domi/

and this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".info").tytabs({
            tabinit:"1",
            fadespeed:"fast"
        });
    });
</script>
```

icon switcher dosent work

Comment: Have you included the plugin library **after** including the jquery library?

Comment: you have to include jquery library before all plugin libraries

Comment: +1 asprin: the very first error is because scrolltop.js needs jquery, you shall link jquery before that one

Comment: Check the order you're including the plugin for the tytabs function, or if you're including it at all. It needs to be after the main jquery code is included and after any other scripts it relies on

Comment: you have defined scrolling.js in two places , that;s why its giving error. Remove the one at the top of the file above CSS files

Answer (score 0):

Simply rearrange your scripts in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tytabs.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scrolltop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script async src="analytics.js"></script>
```

The jQuery core library should be included first followed by the other plugin code.

Comment: It;s because you have scrolltop.js at the top. remove that

Comment: i did that and still nothing

Comment: For debugging purposes, just keep `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="tytabs.jquery.min.js"></script>` and see if that works. Remove the other script tags (analytics.js, scrolltop.js, and modernizr.custom.63321.js)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):27 same error

Comment: I get a blank page on vising the link

Comment: As a last option, I can only suggest removing all the blank spaces inside the `tytabs` function

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `scrollTop.js` in two places.

One is at the top of css files. And jquery is not loaded before that. That's why you are getting error.

```
        <title>Smykke Galleriet</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.1.css" />
        <script src="scrolltop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Remove that line and it will work properly.

Comment: Still dont work ;< Can someone give me another piece of advices ?